# My eyes were accidentally exposed to high infrared radiation and they hurt, why?

Tags: neuroscience

My eyes were exposed to high amounts of infrared radiation. They hurt - why?

Comment: I think you should contact doctor rather than asking question here.

Comment: @Dexter You should talk to a doctor, yes. However, I think we still need to be willing to answer the question! The person asking isn't asking about how to take care of their eyes, but rather WHY their eyes hurt!

Comment: Every kind of electromagnetic radiation can burn if the intensity is strong enough. If you didn't feel burning heat or something like that, then most probably something else causes your eye problems.

Comment: Be aware that most of the light sources are not coherent, like lasers, so they emit on different frequencies. Usually we filter the unwanted frequencies, e.g. by solarium we filter the higher frequencies than UVA.

Comment: @L.B. I said contact doctor because sometimes people try to self medicate. It is better not to give any medical advice on open online forum.

Comment: @Dexter Haha, true, I do it all the time :)